# Flag a field whenever AtTask task changes

Tags: attask

Is it possible to have a field (or create a new one) in AtTask which can be flagged (say 1) whenever there are any changes to the task?

This is so that our external system can detect based on this field, the tasks that have changed, and correspondingly update it in the external system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lastUpdateDate timestamp field to accomplish the same objective. You can store a date externally and then query AtTask for all objects that have been updated since the stored timestamp. Example:

```
https://yourdomain.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v4.0/project/search?lastUpdateDate=2014-01-01T17:00:00:000-0700&lastUpdateDate_Mod=gte
```

This will return all projects that have been updated since 2014-01-01T17:00:00:000-0700.